# Is there any way of using match against statement in Propel (ORM)?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, propel, match-against

Is there any way of using match against statement in Propel (ORM)? It is odd I cannot find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct support. Perhaps a custom query?

```
$con = Propel::getConnection(BookPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
$sql = "SELECT title,category FROM articles WHERE MATCH(title,category) AGAINST (:text); 
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':text' => 'My match text'));
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will help

Answer (score 1):

At least in Propel 1.7 it works with a where() clause:

```
UserQuery::create()->where('MATCH('
. UserPeer::Name
. ') AGAINST(?)', $name)->find();
```