# Fulltext searching in Propel 1.6

Tags: search, propel, full-text-search

Could you give me real example how to make fulltext searching in pure Propel 1.6, please? I don't use Symfony.

Comment: What research have you got so far? Is there anything in the (excellent) docs about this?

Comment: Full text search is mentioned in the README for the symfony plugin on Github, maybe look into that? (I know you're not using symfony, but read the code and see how it works - it will be using raw Propel at some point.) https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin

Comment: You can also run SQL manually in Propel if you need to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655710/match-against-statement-in-propel

Comment: Thanks halfer for your quick response. I have used your link to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655710/match-against-statement-in-propel now it works. I found that advice before but I made some beginner mistakes

Comment: Great. If you would, please add details of your solution as an answer, and tick it as accepted. It will be of use to people who have the same problem in the future.